# GRAILS : Need help in each statement

Tags: javascript, grails

I am new to JavaScript, I have a very basic question.

I have this each statement within an alert in my each statement which is working perfectly:

```
alert( " <g:each in="${index}"> ${""+it.indexDate+""+it.value }  </g:each>  " );
```

Now I have this variable:

```
var todaysDate = new Date ;
```

I want to check if the above indexDate is same as todaysDate.

How can i exactly do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should really mention that.

Comment: Try JavaScript please. The JavaScript code could work with operator '==' as noted. next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare to the precision of miliseconds, you compare the `getTime()` value of both `Date` Object.

```
if (it.indexDate.getTime() === todaysDate.getTime() ) {
  //Do something when todaysDate is it.indexDate
}
```

If you want to compare only the Date part, you compare the `getDate()` value.

```
if (it.indexDate.getDate() === todaysDate.getDate() ) {
  //Do something when todaysDate is it.indexDate
}
```

In Grails framework, you use the following code

```
<g:each in=${index}>
  <g:set var="todaysDate" value="${new Date()}" />
  <g:if test="${it.indexDate.getTime() === todaysDate.getTime()}">
      //code when the comparison passes
  </if>
</g:each>
```

Comment: thanks , kindly tell me the exact location where i need tow rite this if statement , as if i write your above statement outside each , it sayd unresolved variable "it"

Comment: `getDate()` only returns the day of the month (1-31) so Jan 12 would return the same value as Feb 12.  I doubt this is what the OP wants.

Comment: thanks steven , i am very close now , but instead of this  value="${new Date()}"    in ur code above , i want to use myDate instead of new date , which is coming from user i have saved it above, how can i use it here  , as it saying unresolvec "myDate"

Comment: @junaidp Maybe you could try define the Date variable in this line `<g:set var="todaysDate" value="${new Date()}" />` where you get the `Date` from the user?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `==` operator:

```
if(indexDate == todaysDate) {
  alert("They're the same!");
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this need to match the time of day also?

Comment: but where i write this if statement , if i write outside each , it says unresolved variable "indexDate " , if i write inside each it say unresolved variable todaysDate

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if these two dates are the same day (but not necessarily the same hours, mins and seconds), you can do the comparison either of these ways:

```
function getNumDays(date) {
    return(Math.floor(date.getTime()/(1000*60*60*24)));
}

if (getNumDays(it.indexDate) == getNumDays(todaysDate)) {
    // same day
}
```

Or, a more brute force way that compares year, month, day of month:

```
if ((it.indexDate.getFullYear() == todaysDate.getFullYear()) && 
   (it.indexDate.getDate() == todaysDate.getDate()) &&
   (it.indexDate.getDay() == todaysDate.getDay())) {
   // same day
}
```

The first option gets the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 and calculates how many days have elapsed since then (rounding down).  If both date values are the same number of days since then, then they are the same day.

The second option compares the 4 digit year, the month and the day of the month and if all three are equal, then it must be the same day.

Comment: thanks , but where i write this if statement , if i write outside each , it says unresolved variable "indexDate " , if i write inside each it say unresolved variable todaysDate